# Print the length of strings as numbers

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to define a function, which prints the exact length of the string (which may be any length - based on user input), as numbers. For example:

```
string = "hello"
```

length of the string is 5, so the python prints this line:

```
"1 2 3 4 5"
```

and if

```
string = "notnow"
```

length of string is 6, so the python prints this line:

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Also, your length of the string calculation is off by one.

Comment: Yeah, there are 5 letters in "hello"

Comment: Reading material: functions `len`, `range`, `str`; use `" ".join` for additional credit :)

Comment: I can't figure out what to do with it. So far I have:

a = str(input("Please enter a phrase: "))
length_of_a = len(a)

Comment: It's part of a LONG assignment - I have done the bit where I have to take a string and remove a character at random and then move that character to the END of the string.

I just can't figure out how to make python print the length of the strings (starting from 1 and not 0) till the last character + 1.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
ret = ""
string = "hello"

for i in range(len(string)):
    ret+=str(i+1) + " "

print ret
```

`len("hello")` is 5 and `len("notnow")` is 6. I don't know why these numbers in your question is off by 1.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with enumerate, which does a very quick counting by character (in this case), and can be used with list comprehension very tidily:

```
for i, char in enumerate(string):
    print i+1,
```

where `string` is any string you want (from user input, or whatever). The `print i+1` prints the enumeration (plus one, since indexing starts at 0) and the comma keeps it all on the same line.

You can use this along with the standard:

```
string = raw_input('Enter some text: ')
```

or `input` if you're in python 3.X

Answer (score 1):

```
string1 = "hello"
string2 = "notnow"

def lenstr(s):
    return ' '.join(map(str, range(1, len(s) + 1)))

print(lenstr(string1))
print(lenstr(string2))
print(lenstr(''))
```

In the case where the string has length 0, it prints nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could print x, x-1, x-2 and so on as long as the integer is positive.

Answer (score 0):

For this kinda problems, I like to combine list comprehension and a join. Something like this:

```
def indexify(text): 
    return ' '.join([str(x + 1) for x in range(len(text))])
```